# Decreasing function show with image

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If $f$: (0,$\infty$) -> $R$ is a function with image $R$($f$) that has the property 1. $\lim_{x\to 0}$ $f(x)$=$\infty$ 2. $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ $f(x)$=1

Show: if $f$ is decreasing  then $R$($f$) $\subset$ [1,$\infty$)

Show: if $f$ is continu then (1,$\infty$) $\subset$ $R$($f$)

Now i did graph the function when it approaches 0 and then goes to infinity and also when x goes to infinity then the function will approach 1. Now i was not sure as how to proceed with "showing" this. I could not think of any theorem who could help me to start. I dont think the intermediate value theorem will be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If there exists $x_0>0$ such that $f(x_0)<1$, then by the decrease of $f$ we have $f(x)\leqslant f(x_0)$ for all $x\geqslant x_0$. This implies $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) \leqslant f(x_0)<1$, this is contradiction. Hence $f(x)\geqslant 1$ for all $x>0$.

2) $f$ is continuous. Let $x_0 >1$, we need to prove that $x_0 \in R(f)$, i.e., there has a point $y_0>0$ such that $f(y_0)=x_0$. Since $f(x)\to \infty $ as $x\to 0^+$, there exists $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)>x_0$; Since $f(x)\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$, there exists $x_2$ such that $f(x_2)<x_0$; . By the continuity of $f$ and intermediate value theorem, we get the desired point $y_0$.

Comment: Cant we use the intermediate value theorem on 1.? I thought i need to use it to "show" it.

Comment: Note that the intermediate value theorem is only available for continuous function.

Comment: Yes. But when questions are asked regarding "show" or "proof" then i always try to search for a theorem.